scrapy 2.11.2 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.cmdline'
I created a virtual environment and installed scrapy through pip, but when I ran the scrapy command, I got the error below. I'm hoping someone might've ran into this and is able to help troubleshoot.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\pipeline\apps\python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "P:\pipeline\apps\python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "P:\pipeline\apps\python\.scrapy-venv\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.cmdline'

I'm using Python 3.10.11 on Windows 11 and scrapy 2.11.2, installed through python -m pip install scrapy. pip version is 24.0.
Thanks in advance!
--
Things I tried:

Uninstalling and reinstalling scrapy through pip (as well as a pip --upgrade --force-reinstall scrapy) in the virtual environment.
Deleting the virtual environment and creating it again.
Removing my Python installation, restarting my machine and starting the process again.


Upload the part of code that creates this error.

Scrapy documentation has platform specific installation notes related to Windows as often it is not possible to install scrapy on windows by just pip install scrapy https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.11/intro/install.html#platform-specific-installation-notes
In general it is 2 directions:

Build C++ build tools (required for some python libs for scrapy).
Use Anaconda (or miniconda) environment (not pip)

